# How do I cope with no friends, freedom or internet access?

Tags: teen, independence, internet, depression, foster-parenting

I'm 15 and living in care. School laptops are my lifeline but many social media websites, even ones like Reddit and Pinterest, are blocked. At home the only things I can do to pass time in my bedroom include reading, writing, solving puzzles, studying, crafting, drawing, sleeping and daydreaming. I can't play video games or watch Netflix as I'm only allowed to do that downstairs where everyone can see.
I am also followed by a car everywhere I go. When I tried running away (only temporarily, like for 2 hours with the intention of coming back) the police were literally called.
I also can't spend any money on my own, at all. Neither can I get a bike.

I am severely depressed and traumatised. What can I do? The home (and my social worker) don't understand that as an INTP 5w4, I absolutely love the internet to comfort me, feed my appetite for knowledge, and replace human connection. The two other kids in my home are INxP's who are allowed their phones all the time so stay in their bedroom, occasionally leaving. I want to be like that.

Comment: What country are you from? because if it were here i would have called child protective services :|

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what an INTP 5w4 or INxP is...

Comment: @LaurentS. INTP refers to the Meyers Briggs personality typology. It mean Introverted, iNtuitive, Thinking, Perceiving.  Intuitive means being primarily focused on an internal mental world. Thinking means a logical evidential approach rather than an emotional one (think Spock vs McCoy). Perceiving means living in the moment rather than planning ahead.  However the MB types are not well thought of in Psychology, where the OCEAN big 5 traits are reckoned a better model. INTP is the classic geek type.

Comment: Can you explain why these limits are imposed, and why the other kids don’t seem to be treated so strict?